# Custom RoleProvider and Could not load type

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have custom membership and role provider, on debuggin I've got following error:

**Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Classiffieds.WebProviders.ClassiffiedsRoleProvider'.**:

Source error:

```
 <add applicationName="/" 
      name="ClassiffiedsRoleProvider" 
      type="Classiffieds.WebProviders.ClassiffiedsRoleProvider" />
```

**Web.config is set like this**

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="ClassiffiedsRoleProvider">
   <providers>
      <clear />
      <add applicationName="/" 
            name="ClassiffiedsRoleProvider" 
            type="Classiffieds.WebProviders.ClassiffiedsRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
</roleManager>
```

**ClassifiedsRoleProvider.cs**

```
namespace Classiffieds.WebProviders
{
    public sealed class ClassiffiedsRoleProvider: RoleProvider
    ...
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Update:
    Custom role provider is in separated project `Classiffieds.WebProviders` with

```
ClassName: ClassiffiedsRoleProvider
```

and

```
AssemblyName: Classiffieds.WebProviders
```

After suggestions I tried with following

```
<add applicationName="/" 
    name="ClassiffiedsRoleProvider" 
    type="Classiffieds.WebProviders.ClassiffiedsRoleProvider,Classiffieds.WebProviders" />
```

But error message remains 
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly '`Classiffieds.WebProviders`' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Do you have a reference in your web application project to the project with your custom role provider (or a reference to the dll)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most probably your provider is in another assembly. Provide a full name

```
type="Classiffieds.WebProviders.ClassiffiedsRoleProvider, name.of.your.assembly.without.dll"
```

Comment: maybe I'm wrong but I think I'm already set full assembly name in type="Classiffieds.WebProviders.ClassiffiedsRoleProvider" />

Comment: Nope, I can see only namespace.typename. You miss comma and the assembly name (", Classifieds.WebProvider" or whatever the assembly name is).

Comment: sorry I see that now, question is updated, but my problem remains the same.

Comment: Where is your class defined? What assembly? What is the name of this assembly? Without the knowledge of the structure of your solution, it is difficult to give a single yet precise shot.

Comment: What if you do `Type type=Type.GetType("Classiffieds.WebProviders.ClassiffiedsRoleProvider, Classiffieds.WebProviders")` in your Application_Start (with first removing the provider from the web config). What do the exception and innerexception say?

Comment: I commented out roleManager in web.config and add breakpoint to  ... GetType code in app.start. On debugging type variable is null.

Comment: Could you try `Type.GetType("Classiffieds.WebProviders.ClassiffiedsRoleProvider, Classiffieds.WebProviders", true)` and paste exception message and the inner exception message?

Comment: Exception is System.IO.FileNotFoundException. Inner exception is null, and the Message is Could not load file or assembly 'Classiffieds.WebProviders' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Solved this with moving role and membership providers to domain.security namespace. Still cannot figure what is the problem. Many thanks for you're time.

Answer (score 2):

If you have your role provider class in the App_Code folder, then you need to change the  "Build Action" property for the class file to "compile".